# Chef: Error executing action `start` on resource 'service[mysql-foo]' and undefined method

Tags: mysql, linux, vagrant, chef-infra, knife

Could you help me resolve problem with "Error executing action `start` on resource 'service[mysql-foo]' and "undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass". I installed last version cookbook "MySql" from official site and created simple recipe how you can see below in detailed log.

Thank you for your attention to this matter.

```
Creating new client for APP-SRV
Creating new node for APP-SRV
Connecting to 127.0.0.1
127.0.0.1 -----> Existing Chef installation detected
127.0.0.1 Starting the first Chef Client run...
127.0.0.1 Starting Chef Client, version 12.15.19
127.0.0.1 resolving cookbooks for run list: ["mysql"]
127.0.0.1 Synchronizing Cookbooks:
127.0.0.1   - mysql (8.1.1)
127.0.0.1 Installing Cookbook Gems:
127.0.0.1 Compiling Cookbooks...
127.0.0.1 Converging 1 resources
127.0.0.1 Recipe: mysql::default
127.0.0.1   * mysql_service[foo] action create
127.0.0.1     * mysql_server_installation_package[foo] action install
127.0.0.1       * apt_package[mysql-server-5.5] action install (up to date)
127.0.0.1       * apt_package[perl-Sys-Hostname-Long] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)
127.0.0.1       * execute[Initial DB setup script] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)
127.0.0.1        (up to date)
127.0.0.1     * mysql_service_manager_upstart[foo] action create
127.0.0.1       * group[mysql] action create (up to date)
127.0.0.1       * linux_user[mysql] action create (up to date)
127.0.0.1       * service[mysql] action stop (up to date)
127.0.0.1       * service[mysql] action disable (up to date)
127.0.0.1       * file[/etc/mysql/my.cnf] action delete (up to date)
127.0.0.1       * file[/etc/my.cnf] action delete (up to date)
127.0.0.1       * link[/usr/share/my-default.cnf] action create (skipped due to not_if)
127.0.0.1       * directory[/etc/mysql-foo] action create (up to date)
127.0.0.1       * directory[/etc/mysql-foo/conf.d] action create (up to date)
127.0.0.1       * directory[/run/mysql-foo] action create (up to date)
127.0.0.1       * directory[/var/log/mysql-foo] action create (up to date)
127.0.0.1       * directory[/var/lib/mysql-foo] action create (up to date)
127.0.0.1       * template[/etc/mysql-foo/my.cnf] action create (up to date)
127.0.0.1       * apt_package[apparmor] action install (up to date)
127.0.0.1       * directory[/etc/apparmor.d/local/mysql] action create (up to date)
127.0.0.1       * template[/etc/apparmor.d/local/usr.sbin.mysqld] action create (up to date)
127.0.0.1       * template[/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld] action create (up to date)
127.0.0.1       * template[/etc/apparmor.d/local/mysql/foo] action create (up to date)
127.0.0.1       * service[foo apparmor] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)
127.0.0.1       * bash[foo initial records] action run
127.0.0.1         - execute "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20161110-4682-2n48bo"
127.0.0.1
127.0.0.1
127.0.0.1   * mysql_service[foo] action start
127.0.0.1     * mysql_service_manager_upstart[foo] action start
127.0.0.1       * template[/usr/sbin/mysql-foo-wait-ready] action create (up to date)
127.0.0.1       * template[/etc/init/mysql-foo.conf] action create (up to date)
127.0.0.1       * service[mysql-foo] action start
127.0.0.1
127.0.0.1         ================================================================================
127.0.0.1         Error executing action `start` on resource 'service[mysql-foo]'
127.0.0.1         ================================================================================
127.0.0.1
127.0.0.1         NoMethodError
127.0.0.1         -------------
127.0.0.1         undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
127.0.0.1
127.0.0.1         Resource Declaration:
127.0.0.1         ---------------------
127.0.0.1         # In /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/mysql/libraries/mysql_service_manager_upstart.rb
127.0.0.1
127.0.0.1          42:       service mysql_name do
127.0.0.1          43:         provider Chef::Provider::Service::Upstart
127.0.0.1          44:         supports status: true
127.0.0.1          45:         action [:start]
127.0.0.1          46:       end
127.0.0.1          47:     end
127.0.0.1
127.0.0.1         Compiled Resource:
127.0.0.1         ------------------
127.0.0.1         # Declared in /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/mysql/libraries/mysql_service_manager_upstart.rb:42:in `block
in <class:MysqlServiceManagerUpstart>'
127.0.0.1
127.0.0.1         service("mysql-foo") do
127.0.0.1           provider Chef::Provider::Service::Upstart
127.0.0.1           action [:start]
127.0.0.1           supports {:status=>true}
127.0.0.1           retries 0
127.0.0.1           retry_delay 2
127.0.0.1           default_guard_interpreter :default
127.0.0.1           service_name "mysql-foo"
127.0.0.1           pattern "mysql-foo"
127.0.0.1           declared_type :service
127.0.0.1           cookbook_name "mysql"
127.0.0.1         end
127.0.0.1
127.0.0.1         Platform:
127.0.0.1         ---------
127.0.0.1         i686-linux
127.0.0.1
127.0.0.1
127.0.0.1       ================================================================================
127.0.0.1       Error executing action `start` on resource 'mysql_service_manager_upstart[foo]'
127.0.0.1       ================================================================================
127.0.0.1
127.0.0.1       NoMethodError
127.0.0.1       -------------
127.0.0.1       service[mysql-foo] (/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/mysql/libraries/mysql_service_manager_upstart.rb line 42)
had an error: NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
127.0.0.1
127.0.0.1       Resource Declaration:
127.0.0.1       ---------------------
127.0.0.1       # In /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/mysql/libraries/mysql_service.rb
127.0.0.1
127.0.0.1        50:           svc = mysql_service_manager(name, &block)
127.0.0.1        51:         when 'sysvinit'
127.0.0.1
127.0.0.1       Compiled Resource:
127.0.0.1       ------------------
127.0.0.1       # Declared in /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/mysql/libraries/mysql_service.rb:50:in `svc_manager'
127.0.0.1
127.0.0.1       mysql_service_manager_upstart("foo") do
127.0.0.1         action [:start]
127.0.0.1         retries 0
127.0.0.1         retry_delay 2
127.0.0.1         default_guard_interpreter :default
127.0.0.1         declared_type :mysql_service_manager
127.0.0.1         cookbook_name "mysql"
127.0.0.1         version "5.5"
127.0.0.1         initial_root_password "vagrant"
127.0.0.1         port "3306"
127.0.0.1         instance "foo"
127.0.0.1         run_user "mysql"
127.0.0.1         run_group "mysql"
127.0.0.1         socket "/run/mysql-foo/mysqld.sock"
127.0.0.1       end
127.0.0.1
127.0.0.1       Platform:
127.0.0.1       ---------
127.0.0.1       i686-linux
127.0.0.1
127.0.0.1
127.0.0.1     ================================================================================
127.0.0.1     Error executing action `start` on resource 'mysql_service[foo]'
127.0.0.1     ================================================================================
127.0.0.1
127.0.0.1     NoMethodError
127.0.0.1     -------------
127.0.0.1     mysql_service_manager_upstart[foo] (/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/mysql/libraries/mysql_service.rb line 50) ha
d an error: NoMethodError: service[mysql-foo] (/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/mysql/libraries/mysql_service_manager_upstart.r
b line 42) had an error: NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
127.0.0.1
127.0.0.1     Resource Declaration:
127.0.0.1     ---------------------
127.0.0.1     # In /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/mysql/recipes/default.rb
127.0.0.1
127.0.0.1       1: mysql_service 'foo' do
127.0.0.1       2:   version '5.5'
127.0.0.1       3:   port '3306'
127.0.0.1       4:   initial_root_password 'vagrant'
127.0.0.1       5:   action [:create, :start]
127.0.0.1       6: end
127.0.0.1      
127.0.0.1
127.0.0.1     Compiled Resource:
127.0.0.1     ------------------
127.0.0.1     # Declared in /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/mysql/recipes/default.rb:1:in `from_file'
127.0.0.1
127.0.0.1     mysql_service("foo") do
127.0.0.1       action [:create, :start]
127.0.0.1       updated true
127.0.0.1       retries 0
127.0.0.1       retry_delay 2
127.0.0.1       default_guard_interpreter :default
127.0.0.1       declared_type :mysql_service
127.0.0.1       cookbook_name "mysql"
127.0.0.1       recipe_name "default"
127.0.0.1       version "5.5"
127.0.0.1       port "3306"
127.0.0.1       initial_root_password "vagrant"
127.0.0.1       install_method "auto"
127.0.0.1       service_manager "auto"
127.0.0.1     end
127.0.0.1
127.0.0.1     Platform:
127.0.0.1     ---------
127.0.0.1     i686-linux
127.0.0.1
127.0.0.1
127.0.0.1 Running handlers:
127.0.0.1 [2016-11-10T11:04:52+03:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
127.0.0.1 Running handlers complete
127.0.0.1 [2016-11-10T11:04:52+03:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
127.0.0.1 Chef Client failed. 3 resources updated in 41 seconds
127.0.0.1 [2016-11-10T11:04:53+03:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
127.0.0.1 [2016-11-10T11:04:53+03:00] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the stacktrace.out file if you file a bug re
port
127.0.0.1 [2016-11-10T11:04:53+03:00] ERROR: mysql_service[foo] (mysql::default line 1) had an error: NoMethodError: mys
ql_service_manager_upstart[foo] (/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/mysql/libraries/mysql_service.rb line 50) had an error: NoMet
hodError: service[mysql-foo] (/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/mysql/libraries/mysql_service_manager_upstart.rb line 42) had an
 error: NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
127.0.0.1 [2016-11-10T11:04:54+03:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfull
y (exit code 1)
```

Comment: Please provide more context to this, at least snippet with your recipe.

Comment: Dear Szymon,

My recipe following:
mysql_service 'foo' do
  version '5.7'
  port '3306'
  initial_root_password 'vagrant'
  action [:create, :start]
end

Cookbook was download from https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/mysql#readme.
If you need more information please give me feedback.
Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure about this code? In your log I can see you are installing 5.5, but you have pasted code with `version 5.7`. There is also [upstream bug](https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/mysql/issues/442), which may be related.

Comment: I installed MySql 5.5 version. Now i try on another environment deploy 5.6 or 5.7 version. 

Thank you.

Comment: Please include the full stack trace from `/var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out`.